# How can I make this form redirect to example.com/i/username

Tags: html, forms, redirect, webforms

This is my html code

```html
<form method="get" action="https://example.com/i">
  Username : <input type="text" name="uname"></input>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="search"></input>
</form>
```

When I search something in it, it redirects to `example.com/i/username/?` but I want it to be redirect to `example.com/i/username`. There should be no `/` and `?` at the end of the url

Comment: Try using .../i/uname

Comment: Use JavaScript for redirect and get the value of the element by JavaScript...i think that way is the way to do that

Comment: @Ashishsah How?

Comment: @Ashishsah Please don't confuse me with your irrelevant comments. I'm expecting for  answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way to go...

```js
var search = document.getElementById('search');
search.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name');

  //Redirect the client to the desired URL, if the name is valid.
  location.href = 'https://example.com/i/' + encodeURIComponent(name.value);
});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="https://example.com/i" id="myForm">
    Username : <input type="text" id="name"></input><br/>
    <input type="button" value="search" id="search"></input>
</form>
```